# Save another object within custom save method

Tags: django, django-models

Every time a user logs their workout, I want to save a transaction log entry for each exercise completed in the workout.

```
class LogBook(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    exercises = models.ManyToManyField(Exercise, through='Measurement')
    workout_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
    notes = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Need to save first to get access to a newly created log's ID            
        super(LogBook, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        workout_list = []
        workout_list.append(self.id)

        exercise_list = [exercise.id for exercise in self.exericises.all()]

class TransactionLog(models.Model):
    EVENT_CHOICES = (
        ('recalc', 'Priority Calculation'),
        ('action', 'Exercise'),
    )
    log_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
    event_type = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=EVENT_CHOICES)
    event_model = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    event_id = models.IntegerField()
```

So from within LogBook's save method, I want to save new TransactionLogs:

```
First log:
event_type = 'action'
event_model = 'workout'
event_id = workout_list[0]

Additional logs:
event_type = 'action'
event_model = 'exercise'
event_id = one log for each id in exercise_list
```

How can I save new TransactionLog models from within LogBook's save method?

As a bonus question, I've already written a view to save transactionlogs when recalculations are made (event_type = 'recalc'):

```
def transaction(user, event, model, id):
    tl = TransactionLog(event_type=event, event_model = model, event_id = id)
    tl.save()
    return
```

If I define a way to save from LogBook's save method, am I "violating" DRY by not somehow calling the transaction function from within LogBook's save method?

Comment: Use `post_save' signal of `LogBook` model.

Comment: could you provide an example as an answer? Would this work even when saving from the admin interface?

Comment: There is already good explanation on django docs, questions here and other websites.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to understand your question, as the answer looks like very simple.

Assuming you remove the `user` parameter of `transaction` because you don't use it, simply add to `LogBook.save`:

```
transaction('action', 'workout', workout_list[0])
for id in exercise_list:
   transaction('action', 'exercise', id)
```

**EDIT**:
The `transaction` function should be, in my opinion, a classmethod of your `TransactionLog` model:

```
@classmethod
def transaction(klass, user, event, model, id):
    tl = klass(event_type=event, event_model = model, event_id = id)
    tl.save()
    return
```

Then, from `view.py`, you call: `TransactionLog.transaction(...)`.

Comment: I should clarify. The transaction() function is in my views.py. LogBook is defined in models.py. I don't know how to call a views function from a models save method.